# How to do horizontal scroll on a div?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to horizontal scroll on a div but unfortunately not able to do that

Below is the div popup -

[image]

This it the `HTML` -

```
<div id="mCSB_4_scrollbar_horizontal" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_4_scrollbar mCS-dark-thin mCSB_scrollTools_horizontal" style="display: block;">
   <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
     <div id="mCSB_4_dragger_horizontal" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-width: 552px; width: 552px; left: 0px; display: block; max-width: 793px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
       <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying using `JavascriptExecuter` but not working

```
    WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.id("mCSB_4_dragger_horizontal"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", scroll);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All posted options are not working in my case but finally I found one solution

In My case when i do scroll, the `<style>` attribute value getting change from

```
<div id="mCSB_4_dragger_horizontal" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-width: 552px; width: 552px; left: 0px; display: block; max-width: 793px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

to

```
<div id="mCSB_4_dragger_horizontal" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-width: 30px; width: 441px; left: 362px; display: block; max-width: 793px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

this way so what I did is I set the `<style>` tag value using `JavascriptExecuter` like this -

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('mCSB_4_dragger_horizontal').setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; min-width: 30px; width: 441px; left: 362px; display: block; max-width: 793px;')");
```

and its working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", scroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is to use

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTo()", scroll);
```

This should allow to scroll right to specified element

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.

HTML code:

```
<div class="scroll">
    You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
div.scroll{
    background-color:#00FFFF;
    height:40px; 
    overflowx:scroll; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

By using above CSS property (`overflow-x: scroll;`) you can scroll horizontally.